# Trying to use a facebook login button to send a user to the next page

Tags: html, facebook

I am trying to have a page which forces a user to either input his first name before he can continue or it forces the user to login with Facebook before continuing. I am having trouble moving the user on after he has clicked the Login with Facebook button, I have attempted to do so using the OnLogin function, any help at all would be appreciated. This is my code so far:

```
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
<title>Login</title>
</head>

<Body>
<center><div class="imageContainer"><br><br>Hello, I am Alex. I am here to walk you <br> through an 11 question quiz which will help <br> calculate your resilience level.</div></center>
<center><canvas id="SpeechAnimation"></canvas></center>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="IDLE.js"></script>


<?PHP
$Forename = "";
?>


<FORM NAME = "Login" METHOD = "POST" ACTION = "IntroductionProcess.php">

<center>Forename: <INPUT TYPE = 'TEXT' class=one Name ='Forename'  value="<?PHP print $Forename;?>"></center>

</FORM>


<script type="text/javascript">
if( screen.width <= 480 ) {
        function zoom() {
        document.body.style.zoom = "250%" 
        }
}
</script>


<body onload="zoom()">

<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '(I entered my Real one)',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.7'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>



<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.7";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<center>
<a href = "Link to my Website">
<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="xlarge" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false"></div>
</a>
</center>

<script>
<fb:login-button  onlogin=location.href = 'IntroductionProcess.php';> </fb:login-button> 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't do this. It is a huge annoyance. And a bad practice.

Comment: What do you mean? I am doing this for a job and don't have the choice on what is done, I just have to do it, I would appreciate some help!

Comment: A friendly advice: if you get paid for coding, you should at least read a few tutorials. And don't publish the URL of your page... Or your appID on a public page. BTW your problem is a basic syntax problem, but I'm not able to help more, as I find this practice unethical. In the whole: the page is just an email address-FB login fetcher site for getting young, probably unstable people's addresses. These people are the most vulnerable digital citizens. They should have the option to remain anonymous.

Comment: read this, and use javascript redirection in FB.login: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: _“I have attempted to do so using the OnLogin function”_ – that: `onlogin=location.href = 'IntroductionProcess.php';` is not a function, but just invalid code.